# npm run dev compiles server and client, but browser shows 404 error

Tags: next.js, localhost

I have a nextjs based ReactJS+Typescript website and my OS is windows 11.
When I do `npm run dev`, I get such output in terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\hosap\Documents\Programming\NextJSApplication\next-typescript> npm run dev

> next-typescript@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Loaded env from C:\Users\hosap\Documents\Programming\NextJSApplication\next-typescript\.env
event - compiled client and server successfully in 1315 ms (150 modules)
wait  - compiling /_error (client and server)...
event - compiled client and server successfully in 219 ms (151 modules)
warn  - Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/fast-refresh-reload
```

Message shows compiled client and server successfully, but when I visit `localhost:3000`,
my browser just shows

[image]

As you see here, browser is receiving 404 error from localhost:3000

[image]

The project structure looks like this:

```
.next/ (creates automatically when I do npm run dev) 
.swc/
.vscode/
   settings.json
.VSCodeCounter/
node_modules/
public/
   images/
   logo/
   favicon.ico
src/
   components/
   elements/
   functions/
   lib/
   pages/
   styles/
.env
.eslintrc.json
.gitignore
environment.d.ts
jest.config.js
next-env.d.ts
next.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md
setupTests.js
tsconfig.json
```

structure of /pages folder

```
pages/
   api/
      search.ts
   search/
   _app.tsx
   _document.tsx
   404.tsx
   about-us.tsx
   index.tsx
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js']
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-typescript",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.12",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.0",
    "eslint": "^8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^26.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.11",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "next-router-mock": "^0.9.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

environment.d.ts

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production'
      API_KEY: string
      URL: string
    }
  }
}

export {}
```

The project worked until 2 days ago, but now it doesn't work on all my local branches.
I am not sure if my last change fucked up the project but I did not have problem like this when I was working with that.

And
`npm run start` also shows same 404 error.
What is causing this problem?

What I tried:

1. npm ci
2. Restarting the computer
3. Removing empty export in `environment.d.ts`

nothing worked :(

Answer (score 0):

Next.js 13 uses `app` folder for the application. You do not have this folder in your sources. Can that cause the problem?

When using the (legacy) `pages` folder the standard structure is to have this folder directly under the project root folder.

Comment: I am not sure .. I had the same project structure 2 days ago too but it worked until 2 days ago

Comment: Did you upgrade to Next.js 13 in the past two days? Or change the file structure? I suggest to try both suggestion with a simple index file.

Comment: no, I did not update Next version. It already had version `13.1.1`

Comment: My last change was I installed a package `next-router-mock`, created some jest testing code and added pageExtensions options to nextConfig

Comment: Looks like using app instead of pages doesn't work for me either. Set `experimental:{appDir:true}` in `next.config.js`  but I still get 404 error

Comment: The reason was I had wrong values for `pageExtensions` inside next.config.js

Comment: Great that you found the cause of the problem.

Comment: In my case, it was because of an empty `Pages` folder in my `src`

Answer (score 0):

The reason was I had wrong `pageExtensions` values in `next.config.js`. Removed the property and it works. The `pageExtensions` will only accept that ends with `pages.tsx, pages.ts, pages.jsx, pages.js` but none of my file has that