# Doing npm run dev in target branch causes 404 error but doing npm run dev in feature branch and checkout to main branch works

Tags: npm, next.js, package.json

Yesterday I created a question here about [npm run dev compiles server and client, but browser shows 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76745473/npm-run-dev-compiles-server-and-client-but-browser-shows-404-error/76745533?noredirect=1#comment135300765_76745533)

The problem was doing `npm run dev`  shows 404 `page not found` error.

[image]

After some tests, I realised my website doesn't work if I do `npm run dev` directly in `main` branch, but website works if I do `npm run dev` on some feature branch and do `git checkout main` .

[image] (working website)

What can cause this problem? For me it sounds really weird that `npm run dev` shows 404 error just on specific branch.

You can find project structure in the link I posted but I will write them here too:

```
.next/ (creates automatically when I do npm run dev) 
.swc/
.vscode/
   settings.json
.VSCodeCounter/
node_modules/
public/
   images/
   logo/
   favicon.ico
src/
   components/
   elements/
   functions/
   lib/
   pages/
   styles/
.env
.eslintrc.json
.gitignore
environment.d.ts
jest.config.js
next-env.d.ts
next.config.js
package-lock.json
package.json
README.md
setupTests.js
tsconfig.json
```

pages folder

```
pages/
   api/
      search.ts
   search/
   _app.tsx
   _document.tsx
   404.tsx
   about-us.tsx
   index.tsx
```

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  pageExtensions: ['page.tsx', 'page.ts', 'page.jsx', 'page.js']
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "next-typescript",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.17",
    "@types/react": "18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.10",
    "classnames": "^2.3.2",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.1.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.5.0",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.21.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.12",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.48.0",
    "eslint": "^8.31.0",
    "eslint-config-standard-with-typescript": "^26.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.11",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "next-router-mock": "^0.9.7",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  }
}
```

enviroment.d.ts

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production'
      API_KEY: string
      URL: string
    }
  }
}

export {}
```